# Comma-separated values with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql select group by and string concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083836/sql-select-group-by-and-string-concat)

My SQL table looks like this:

```
City_Code        Post_Code   Post_Code_Description
100               A1          ABC
100               C8          XYZ
100               Z3          MNO
200               D4          LMN
300               E3          IJK
300               B9          RST
```

It's a mapping between `city_code` and `Post_Code`. One `City_Code` can have many `Post Codes`. Now I want to run a query to get something like this:

```
City_Code           Post_Code         Post_Code_Description
100                 A1,C8,Z3          ABC,XYZ,MNO
200                 D4                LMN
300                 E3,B9             IJK,RST
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: if you're using SQL Server, there are a number of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996177/output-a-comma-seperated-list-in-t-sql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string

Comment: *Why* do you want a field with comma separated values? What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: @podiluska: that's not an unusual requirement for display purposes (think reports or an overview)