# Comma Separated values with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My SQL table is like following

```
City_Code     Post_Code    Post_Code_Description
100           A1           ABC
100           C8           XYZ
100           Z3           MNO
200           D4           LMN
300           E3           IJK
300           B9           RST
```

It's a mapping between city_code and Post_Code. One City_Code has many Post Codes. Now i want to run a Query to get something like following

```
City_Code     Post_Code    Post_Code_Description
100           A1,C8,Z3     ABC,XYZ,MNO
200           D4           LMN
300           E3,B9        IJK,RST
```

Can you please help me with thisy SQL table is like following

Comment: First sentence "My SQL table is like following" but the space between "My" and "SQL" hmm... Now I'm not sure, I removed tag :)

Comment: i imagine the answer is exactly the same as your previous question [Comma-separated values with SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670409/comma-separated-values-with-sql-query)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT City_Code, 
      Post_Code = 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Post_Code
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.City_Code = a.City_Code 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
      Post_Code_Description=
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Post_Code_Description
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.City_Code = a.City_Code 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY City_Code
```

Comment: I believe it should be stuff(..., 1, 1, '') else losing a character.

Comment: @crokusek No. The SELECT prefixes with 2 characters <comma> and <space> so the STUFF needs to remove 2 characters from position 1. You'd be right if it was just adding a comma.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using MySQL you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select City_Code, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Code) Post_Code, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Code_Description) post_code_description
from yourtable
group by City_Code
```

For SQL Server you can use [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx?ppud=4) and [`FOR XML PATH()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
select city_code,
    Stuff((SELECT ', ' + post_code 
            FROM yourtable t2
            where t1.city_code = t2.city_code
            FOR XML path('')),1,1,'') Post_Code,
    Stuff((SELECT ', ' + post_code_description
            FROM yourtable t2
            where t1.city_code = t2.city_code
            FOR XML path('')),1,1,'') post_code_description
from yourtable t1
group by city_code
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @user1711287 please see my edit, I added an answer for SQL Server

Comment: Bit odd to say that for SQL Server you can use `STUFF`. It is `XML PATH` that does all the work. `STUFF` just sneaks in at the end and removes the surplus comma.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are correct, updated to include link to `FOR XML PATH()`

Comment: nice answer :) btw, any reason why you removed all the tag in the questions  `MySQL-Pivot`? anything wrong with creating new tag?

Comment: @JohnWoo nothing wrong with creating a new tag but it seems redundant considering most questions are tagged with `MySQL` and `PIVOT`, I don't think there is a need for `MySQL-PIVOT`.  Most `PIVOT` question even `MySQL` ones can fit in the normal `PIVOT` tag, I think adding one will just be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
select city_code,substring((select ',' + post_code  
from city b where a.city_code=b.city_code
for xml path('')
),2,100)as post_code,
substring((select ',' + post_code_description 
from city c where a.city_code=c.city_code
for xml path('')
),2,100)as post_code_description
from city a
group by a.city_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive query for this:

```
--Prepare Dummy Data
;WITH CITIES 
     AS (SELECT 100   AS City_Code, 
                'A1'  AS Post_code, 
                'ABC' AS Post_Code_Description 
         UNION 
         SELECT 100   AS City_Code, 
                'C8'  AS Post_code, 
                'XYZ' AS Post_Code_Description 
         UNION 
         SELECT 100   AS City_Code, 
                'Z3'  AS Post_code, 
                'MNO' AS Post_Code_Description 
         UNION 
         SELECT 200   AS City_Code, 
                'D4'  AS Post_code, 
                'LMN' AS Post_Code_Description 
         UNION 
         SELECT 300   AS City_Code, 
                'E3'  AS Post_code, 
                'IJK' AS Post_Code_Description 
         UNION 
         SELECT 300   AS City_Code, 
                'B9'  AS Post_code, 
                'RST' AS Post_Code_Description), 
--Add Row numbers to each row
     PREPARE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER () 
                  OVER ( 
                    PARTITION BY CITY_CODE 
                    ORDER BY CITY_CODE) RN 
         FROM   CITIES),
--Start Recursive CTE 
     RECURSIVE 
     AS (
--Anchor Query
         SELECT CITY_CODE, 
                CAST(POST_CODE AS VARCHAR(MAX))             Post_code, 
                CAST(POST_CODE_DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
                Post_Code_Description, 
                1                                           AS LEVEL, 
                RN 
         FROM   PREPARE 
         WHERE  RN = 1 
         UNION ALL 
--Recursive Query
         SELECT T1.CITY_CODE, 
                T1.POST_CODE + ',' + T2.POST_CODE, 
                T1.POST_CODE_DESCRIPTION + ',' 
                + T2.POST_CODE_DESCRIPTION, 
                T2.LEVEL + 1, 
                T1.RN 
         FROM   PREPARE AS T1 
                INNER JOIN RECURSIVE AS T2 
                        ON T1.RN = T2.RN + 1 
                           AND T1.CITY_CODE = T2.CITY_CODE) 
--Final Results
SELECT T1.CITY_CODE, 
       T1.POST_CODE, 
       T1.POST_CODE_DESCRIPTION 
FROM   RECURSIVE T1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT CITY_CODE, 
                          COUNT(*) cnt 
                   FROM   CITIES 
                   GROUP  BY CITY_CODE)T2 
               ON T1.CITY_CODE = T2.CITY_CODE 
WHERE  T1.LEVEL = T2.CNT
```