# SQL Cross-Table Referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so I've got two tables. One table (`table 1`) contains a column `Books_Owned_ID` which stores a series of numbers in the form of `1,3,7`. I have another table (`table 2`) which stores the Book names in one column and the book ID in another column.

What I want to do is create an SQL code which will take the numbers from `Books_Owned_ID`and display the names of those books in a new column. Like so:

```
|New Column  |
 Book 1 Name
 Book 2 Name
 Book 3 Name
```

I can't wrap my head around this, it's simple enough but all the threads I look on get really confusing.

`Table1` contains the following columns:

```
|First_Name| Last_Name| Books_Owned_ID |
```

`Table2` contains the following columns:

```
|Book_Name|Book_ID|
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: are the tags `Books_Owned_Id` and `Book_ID` the same? if so you can join on them

Comment: Are the values in "Books_Owned_ID" really a comma delimited list of "Book_ID"'s?  If so, that's why you are having trouble.  You need a 3rd 1-to-many table that connects "table 1" with "table 2".

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server with the MS Management Studio.

Comment: Wait, no, uh...  This is a design issue in your datastructure.  You probably want three tables instead of two: People, jtPeople_Books, and Books.  The current design will probably cause you difficulties in the future.

Comment: I'm thinking separating by commas is a bad idea, is there a better way to separate the numbers in the one column?

Comment: @DylanB - you don't need a cursor for this, you can use FOR XML

Comment: separating by commas is a bad idea, you need another table

Comment: In TSQL you can use [STUFF and FOR XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671117/comma-separated-values-with-sql-query) to get a comma separated list.

Comment: @user2989408 - that is only useful to go from a relational to a comma separated list -- this data is starting as comma separated -- FOR XML won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of this centers around data normalisation... Each fact is stored only once (and so is "authoritative"). You should also get into the habit of only storing a single fact in any field.

So, imagine the following table layouts...

```
Books
    Id, Name, Description

Users
    Id, Username, EmailAddress, PasswordHash, etc....

BooksOwned
    UserId, BookId
```

So if a single user owns multiple books, there will be multiple entries in the `BooksOwned` table...

```
UserId, BookID
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
```

Indicates that User 1 owns books 1 through 3.

The reason to do it this way is that it makes it much easier to query in future. You also treat BookId as an Integer instead of a string containing a list - so you don't need to worry about string manipulation to do your query.

The following would return the name of all books owned by the user with `Id = 1`

```
SELECT Books.Name
FROM   BooksOwned
       INNER JOIN Books
           ON BooksOwned.BookId = Books.Id
WHERE  BooksOwned.UserId = 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was referring to! Thanks for your help @Basic

Comment: My pleasure - it's always nice to find someone who wants to understand. Hope to see you around in future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an inner join.  [This is a great example/reference for these](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

```
SELECT Book_Name FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table1.Books_Owned_ID = Table2.Book_ID
```

**EDIT** [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6abca/2)

I will work on getting the column comma split working.  It wont be a lot extra for this.

**EDIT 2** [See this answer to build a function to split your string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878964/300913)  Then you can do this:

```
SELECT Book_Name FROM Table2 
WHERE Book_ID IN(SELECT FN_ListToTable(',',Table1.Books_Owned_ID) FROM Table1 s)
```

Comment: But that would not give you a comma separated list of Book names.

Comment: Updated answer with example from previous SO questions that splits a comma delimited field and can be used.

Comment: And if he wanted to convert those results back to a comma list he could use FOR XML as my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

Answer (score 1):

You need a function which takes a comma separated list and returns a table.  This is slow and fundamentally a bad idea.  Really all this does is convert this way of doing it to be like the data model I describe below. (see ProfessionalAmateur's answer for an example of this).

If you are just starting change your data model.  Make a linking table.  Like this:

Okay, so I've got two tables. One table (table 1) contains a column Books_Owned_ID which stores a series of numbers in the form of 1,3,7. I have another table (table 2) which stores the Book names in one column and the book ID in another column.

What I want to do is create an SQL code which will take the numbers from Books_Owned_IDand display the names of those books in a new column. Like so:

Person Table

```
 |First_Name| Last_Name| Person_ID |
```

Book Table

```
 |Book_Name|Book_ID|
```

PersonBook Table

```
 |PersonID|BookID|
```

This table can have more than one row for each person.