# SQL comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using this query in another big query.
I need this query to return comman separated values (so John,David,Brian,Jake) and without using any intermediate variable.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Could you please provide necessary SQL?

```
SELECT
    --@listStr = (COALESCE(@listStr + ',', '') + ShortName)
X.ShortName
FROM
    (
    SELECT 'John' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'David' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brian' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jake' AS ShortName 
    ) X
```

Comment: what database you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Is SQL your only option or could you concatenate the results in the app/reporting layer - I only ask because I hate the current ways that are available (cursors, `STUFF`/`FOR XML`, etc.) because they either are too complicated to understand or don't perform as well.  It is _much_ simpler to accomplish in an app or report.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma Separated values with SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671117/comma-separated-values-with-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `STUFF` function, `FOR XML PATH` can be used to concatenate the values with comma as separator and STUFF removes the leading comma.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + ShortName
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 'John' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'David' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brian' AS ShortName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jake' AS ShortName 
    ) X
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' )
```

Comment: "Use the `STUFF` function" is a gross simplification of this complex method.  Are you able to explain _how_ this works?

Comment: @DStanley, good point, i saw that OP was proficient in SQL to understand this, but will keep in mind as it is useful to others.