# Convert intersection of two columns into two comma-separated values

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns with values

```
letter number
A      1
A      2
A      3
B      1
B      2
```

I want two aggregated, comma-separated, values representing the distinct set of the intersections of `letter` and `number`.

e.g

```
letters numbers
A,B     1,2
A       3
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet which you can share with us?

Comment: check your answer here-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671117/comma-separated-values-with-sql-query

Comment: @Emil What result do you expect if your input contains 1 more row with C, 2? Or the first column has always only 2 distinct values?

Comment: @sepupic I would expect to see:
    letters  numbers
    A,B      1,2
    A          3
    C          2

Comment: @akshaypatil I don't believe the linked answer suffices because it 'pivots' on the one column. I need to get the two comma-separated values from the intersection of the two columns. The accepted answer does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done is, first concatenated the `letter` column group by `number` column. Then given a row number partition by concatenated letters and order by `number`. Then again concatenated the `number` column group by the concatenated

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select *
    from (
        select [number], stuff((
                select ', ' + [letter] 
                from [your_table_name]
                where ([number] = t.[number]) 
                for xml path('')
            )
           , 1, 2, ''
        ) as letters
        from [your_table_name] t
        group by [number]
    )t2
)
select [letters], stuff((
        select ', ' + cast(number as varchar(100)) 
        from cte
        where ([letters] = t.[letters]) 
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 2, ''
) as [numbers]
from cte t
group by [letters];
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/ONR65831)**