# how concatenate on heidisql

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

The issue is that I have each asset to have its tags, that is, number 6 to have 1,5 in a column, and asset 1 to have 1,3,5 PUTTING literally twice "asset_tag.tag_id" copies the same number of that row and separate it by comma

"image" is this
CREATE VIEW image as SELECT asset_tag.asset_id FROM asset_tag GROUP BY asset_tag.asset_id ;

SELECT asset_tag.asset_id, concat_ws(',',asset_tag.tag_id,asset_tag.tag_id) AS etiqueta

FROM    public.asset_tag

-- JOIN PUBLIC.imagen ON asset_tag.asset_id = imagen.asset_id

-- WHERE imagen.asset_id = asset_tag.asset_id

GROUP BY asset_tag.asset_id,asset_tag.tag_id

-- HAVING asset_tag.asset_id = imagen.asset_id
;

data:
asest_id 1 1 1 6 6

tag_id 1 3 5 1 2

That is shown in tag_id 1,3,5 for asset_id 1 , and in the case of asset_id 6 that 1,2 come out

the data is of type integer

I have to get through a subquery but I don't see it,

[image]i want taht the group "6" have "5,1" , el "1" have "1,3,5" , what i`m doing wrong?

i see this : [Sql select group by and string concat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10083836/20100117)

and mine
[image]

Comment: Try using `GROUP_CONCAT`. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: THANKS , but i have and error , the function don`t exists

Comment: Can you translate the above error, sorry I can't read it.

Comment: there is no function group_concat(integer)
line 2:
hint: no function matches on the name and types of arguments. it may be necessary to add explicit type conversion

Comment: The linked question is for MS SQL Server, while this question is tagged with mysql. Which one do you use? Group_concat is available in mysql, but is not available in MS SQL Server.

Comment: HEIDI SQL VERSION 12

Comment: What database are you using? HeidiSql is a tool not SQL language

Comment: in network type, postgre sql

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with mysql and not with postgresql?

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `group_concat()`?